# How to make a diagonal elliptical selection in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I try elliptical marquee tool in Photoshop. But it goes either vertical or horizontal. And when I try to rotate it afterwards it rotates with what's in it. I need to make a diagonal elliptical selection of my subject for a motion blur effect. Is there an option for it?

Answer (score 8):

So... In photoshop, make the ellipse the size and shape that you want. Then, go to the "Select" menu and select "Transform Selection" and rotate/resize the selection. This will not rotate/scale the underlying image, just the selection's "marching ants."

Comment: Perfect answer and still relevant today!